# Should I use storyboard and mercurial for team work?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mercurial

We are going to develop a project in a team of 5 developers, and we are planning to use mercurial.

I want to know if it is a good idea to use storyboards with mercurial, or should I go for .xib?

We are more interested in using storyboards if possible.

I have searched on the net and found very interesting things, but not much about storyboards. That's why I'm posting here.

Any kind of small or big help, article or link is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on how big your project is, and if it's going to have a lot of UI.

Some of the cons of storyboard from the top of my head:

- Storyboard is one single file, so only one person can work on the storyboard at once.
- Only works with iOS 5 or up

I recommend taking a look at [this](http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx) and decide for yourself if you want to use storyboard or not.

Comment: I second the "only one person" part. We've found it difficult to use a storyboard in a project with multiple people.

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards internally are xml files. So I don't see any problems with using mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can use storyboards with any SCM since storyboards are xml files. 
Practically I think it is easier to use xibs in a team since xibs are for one view only and you do not have to merge so often since the chance that someone else touched the xib is smaller than with a storyboard.