# How to manage the development of storyboard when several people edit the storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, storyboard

All of our views are in a single storyboard. After we edit the interfaces we are responsible for, we find it is a disaster when we commit the storyboard. Do any better ways exist that make it easier to manage the storyBoard? Should we write UI with code instead of storyboard or xib? While it is really efficient to use storyboard.

Comment: Seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538510/storyboards-and-svn-conflicts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434581/xcode-4-3-how-to-merge-storyboard-changes-from-two-developers-using-svn

Answer (score 1):

What's generally worked for me and my team is to separate related functionality into different storyboards. So if one person is working on x portion of the app, stick all things x related there. As long as only one person is dealing with each component at a time, there's no chance for conflicts that blow up your whole storyboard.

Another thing to keep in mind if you can only use one storyboard, is to limit who can work on each ViewController in the storyboard. It's not the best idea to have multiple people working on the same controller anyways, since you will both be interfering with each others layout. I have found that as long as we stick to our own components, merges are super easy.

Your solution of using code instead of storyboard is also a very valid way to go about it. The decision between code and xib based approaches depends on the user. Code takes longer to get going, but is super easy to reuse, whereas xibs/storyboards make prototyping a snap but are very hard to reuse.

Comment: As far as I know, we can create only ONE storyboard, but we can use a lot of .xib in app with storyboard, am I right?

Comment: True, you can use as many xibs as you want. I would recommend either using only xibs or only storyboards. It is definitely possible to create more than 1 storyboard. If you mean you can only create one based on some other factor like its a requirement for your project thats one thing, but you are able to use as many storyboards as you would like in a project

Answer (score 1):

You need to read this links:

1. http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx
2. http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Which-is-better-StoryBoard-NIB-162305.S.185584395
3. [Should I use storyboard and mercurial for team work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813325/should-i-use-storyboard-and-mercurial-for-team-work)

Storyboard is one single file, so only one person can work on the storyboard at once. It is essential factor for working with team in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The following post helped me to understand answer on this question:
http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.pt/2012/01/uistoryboard-best-practices.html